# pip3 is not installing packages on Mac

Tags: macos, python-3.x, pip, package

Pip3 is actually installing packages on mac but when I run:

`python --version` on Mac it gives error that:

> -bash:command not found

Comment: I don't think there is enough information for someone to help you here. What is "software name", exactly? What command did you use to install it?

Comment: halfer i was referring to python package when i said software name

Comment: yeah i used pip3 install command to install it

Answer (score 0):

I just deleted the Python 3.5 package and installed again. I did this as Python 3 interpreter was lacking in `usr/bin`. Somehow it solved the problem.